# PDF in the iframe triggering download automatically

Tags: android, html, iframe, mobile, download

I have below iframe in one of the page in my website.

```
<iframe src="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" id="iframe1">
```

But when I open same page in android mobiles chrome browser it is automatically triggering download of file which is mentioned in the iframe. How can I prevent auto triggering of download in mobile devices?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this format:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://yourfile.pdf
```

Just replace http://yourfile.pdf with the link you use.

Comment: You mean the need to replace the src with this?

Comment: Yes, just write like here:

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" id="iframe1">

Comment: This will only work if your PDF is hosted somewhere that's publicly accessible by Google's server, because Google's server simply downloads the content at your url and re-displays it

Comment: @JoeIrby absolutely yes!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it is important to think on the availability to use the convert/viewer in offline mode!

**Why and Because**...

If you use an iframe for a stored document on your server and you would made an webapp, you will must play over HTTPS/SSL. (Offline is over https).

It is not sure that the PDF viewer provides a secure url (1), you will probably problems with CORS and others with the « Same origine » to embed the iframe src (2), and finally, it service must delivers online and offline ! So it recommended to embed in application cache all the resources needed to convert the PDF in canvas.

An all in one solution is strongly recommended I think.
*Using PDF.js and its worker with a runtime script is a good way...*